# Where should I add the JS event to make my links work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, onclick, jquery-events

Not sure of where to add my event, my links work when right-clicking and doing "open in new tab" so they are live, but when I try to just click/touch, they don't work.

```
 // Create mobile main menu dropdown groups
    var mainSideNav = $("#mobile-main-sidebar"),
        mainLinks = $("#mobile-main-menu").find("ul.menu"),
        quickLinks = $("#top-links ul.top_left_ql").clone(),
        mobileMenu = $('<ul id="main-menu-side" class="links inline clearfix"> '+
                            '<li class="menu first"> '+
                                '<a href="/" title="Main Menu" class="menu-link open">Main Menu</a> '+
                                '<div id="main-menu-list" class="menu-content"></div> '+
                            '</li> '+
                            '<li class="menu last"> '+
                                '<a href="/" title="Quick Links" class="menu-link">Quick Links</a> '+
                                '<div id="quick-link-list" class="menu-content" style="display:none;"></div> '+
                            '</li> '+
                        '</ul>');

    quickLinks.addClass("menu").find("li").addClass("leaf");

    mainSideNav.find(".sidebar-inner").append(mobileMenu);

    mainLinks.wrap('<div class="menu-panel"><div class="panel-content"></div></div>');
    $("#mobile-main-menu").appendTo("#main-menu-list");
    $('<div class="panel-content">').append(quickLinks).wrap('<div class="menu-panel">').parent().appendTo("#quick-link-list");

    mainSideNav.find(".menu-link").bind("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.is(".open")){
            $this.next().slideUp('fast',function(){
                $this.removeClass("open");
            });
        } else {
            $this.next().slideDown('fast',function(){
                $this.addClass("open");
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Probably this has something to do with the `e.preventDefault();` line.

Comment: Do you have other click events anywhere else in your code? Is this the full code? As others have said, removing `preventDefault` should do it, if not then something else is going on - post more code.

Comment: Thanks for your help Matthew, I jut updated with more code, I hope this helps, the other events are not related to this piece of code but here is one quick example /// $("#topLinkSelector").find("select.selTopLink").bind("change",function()
   {window.location.href = $(this).find("option:selected").val();}); /// Thanks a lot for your help guys!

Answer (score 2):

Your code exists to *prevent* links from being clickable. That's what `e.preventDefault();` does. If you want regular clicking to work, remove that line.

Comment: Hi Meagar, thanks a lot for your quick response, I tried commenting that line out as well as the (e), just leaving it empty but I got no change on behavior.

Comment: After further examination, I believe I'm not assigning the right class on other pieces of code...